# Tensorflowで1次元の畳み込みを行う方法

Tags: python, tensorflow

現在、下記の構造をtensorflow上で再現することを試みております。
Tutorial等では、2次元の畳み込みを中心に話が展開しており、1次元の畳み込みの正確な記述法が分からない状況です。
正しい実装方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
# 重みを標準偏差0.1の正規分布で初期化
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

# バイアスを標準偏差0.1の正規分布で初期化
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

# 第一層畳み込み層の作成
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

# X2プーリング層の作成
def max_pool_2x128(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1],strides=[1, 2, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
# X4プーリング層の作成
def max_pool_4x128(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 4, 1, 1],strides=[1, 4, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

#第一層畳み込み
with tf.name_scope('conv1') as scope:
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 1, 128, 256])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([256])

    x_image = tf.reshape(images_placeholder, [-1,599,1,128])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

#第一層プーリング X4
with tf.name_scope('pool1') as scope:
    h_pool1 = max_pool_4x128(h_conv1)

#第二層畳み込み
with tf.name_scope('conv2') as scope:
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([4, 1, 256, 256])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([256])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

#第二層プーリング X2
with tf.name_scope('pool2') as scope:
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

#フラット化
with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([73 * 1 * 256, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 73*1*256])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
    #ドロップ層の設定
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

#第二結合層
with tf.name_scope('fc2') as scope:
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, NUM_CLASSES])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([NUM_CLASSES])

#出力層
with tf.name_scope('softmax') as scope:
    y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

return y_conv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 1, 128, 256])
```

ですが、これはフィルターを指定している箇所で `[filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, output_channels]`になります。

なので、4*128pxで、見たところカラー画像なのでチャネルは3

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 128, 3, 32])
```

のようになるかと思います。

その他の部分もサイズの指定が間違っているっぽいです。
詳しくはtensorflowのドキュメントをどうぞ。
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d

Answer (score 0):

一次元用に`tf.nn.conv1d`といものがあります。
この関数の中でtf.nn.conv2d呼んでいるのでconv2d使っていてもあんまり問題ないと思います。
tf.nn.conv1dで書き換えると

```
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv1d(x, W, 1, 'SAME')
```

のようになります。